# Ruby - get const_missing inside a module instead of top level

Tags: ruby

I have  a module called `Plants` which has a `const_missing` method and a class called `Sunflower` inside it. When I call an undefined constant, the const_missing method inside the module is not called. Instead the const_missing inside the `Object` class is called. Is there a way to get the const_missing inside the module to be triggered?

```
module Plants
        def self.const_missing(name)
                puts name
        end

        class Sunflower
                def some_method
                        Grass
                end
        end
end


obj = Plants::Sunflower.new
obj.some_method
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module Plants

  def const_missing(name)
    puts name
  end

  class Sunflower
    extend Plants
    def some_method
      Grass
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, Can you explain why I can't do this without extending the class? Just curious.

Comment: Because `const_missing` needs to be an attribute of the object that references a missing constant.  So you either need to reference a constant in the module or you need to have or have inherited a method in your class. The lexically enclosing scope matter when you define constants but it's largely irrelevant for accessing other objects. (Well, other than how it qualifies the namespace.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

Either change your call to

```
def some_method
  ::Plants::Grass
end
```

to ensure that you're calling Plants::Grass

or move const_missing to Sunflower class